# LINQ - Join 2 tables, Group by DateTime.Month , multiple Counts

Tags: c#, linq

I'm pretty new to C# and LINQ and I'm trying get a list of emails that holds the sum of emails, attachments and user's (the one's that sent the email).

So my current Problem is the Output of my Query is false. The number of email's is equal to the number of attachment's which obvious is wrong.
My Query:

```
var monthQuery = from em in dbEdoka.email
                          join ema in dbEdoka.email_attachment on em.id equals ema.email_id into e
                          from e2 in e.DefaultIfEmpty()
                          group e2 by em.erstellt_am.Month into grouped
                          select new Entities.Month
                          {
                              NameOfMonth = grouped.FirstOrDefault().erstellt_am.ToString(),
                              NumberOfMails = grouped.Distinct().Count(m => m.email_id != null).ToString(),
                              NumberOfAttachments = grouped.Count(a => a.id != null).ToString(),
                              NumberOfUsers = grouped.Select(u => u.erstellt_von).Distinct().Count().ToString()
                          };


        months = monthQuery.ToList();
        Months = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(months);
```

As you can see I had to take **m.email_id** from **dbEdoka.email_attachment** instead of **m.id** from **dbEdoka.email** because it wasn't avaliable (don't know why...). 
Yet I have to count "NumberOfMails", "NumberOfAttachments" and "NumberOfUsers".

Thank you!

Comment: At least include the `email` and `email_attachment` classes.